# Django Design pattern for serving static HTML files

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

In my Django website, I have a lot of static HTML files with content that is not supposed to be rendered depending on request etc. (Static HTML files)

I was wondering what was the best design pattern for that type of files.

Should I create a view for each of those files? Such as in the following:

```
url(r'^howitworks/$', 'how_it_works', name="how_it_works"),

with def how_it_works(request):
    return render_to_response("marketing/howitworks.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or is considered better style to put the html files in a folder inside my STATIC_ROOT and serve directly from there with the STATIC_URL prefix?

What are the pros and cons?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to serve static files from `STATIC_ROOT`/`STATIC_URL`.  You can serve them from any directory.  And yes, serving such files directly by web-server is the best option.